# Laravel 4 One To Many Duplicate Entry After Inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have One To Many association Users -> Pages and i have this code:

```
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    foreach ($pages_array['data'] as $page) {

        $page_record = new Page();

        $page_record->name = $page->name;
        $page_record->access_token = $page->token;
        $page_record->page_id = $page->id;

        User::find($user_id)->pages()->save($page_record);
    }
```

but when im trying to insert them i get SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry...

My question is: How can i insert the record if the record in db not exists and skip inserting when exists ? Thanks a lot

p.p Sorry for my bad en.

Comment: Is your `page_id` an auto-increment field?

Comment: No its is not. By default id is auto-increment

Comment: If you are expecting this to happen and there is no way to code around it not happening, then you can just throw it in a try catch block.  Also as a side note, feel free to use `Auth::user()->pages()->save($page_record)`.  It will save you a call to the database.

Comment: Thanks. And i don't expect this to happen. I just want to insert a record without duplication

Comment: That doesn't really make a whole lot of sense then because if it is a one to many, you are expecting many pages with duplicate user_id's.  Did you by chance put a unique index on that column?

Comment: i put unique index on page_id because i dont want to have duplicate page_id's

Comment: Making it auto increment will ensure you will never have duplicate page_id's and would make your life a lot easier.  The only other way around this would be to figure out a way to make a unique id for the page each time and set it before you save.  Get rid of the page_id column on pages as well.  The id column is the page id.

Comment: id column of page is already auto inc. can't have 2 and page_id is big int because i need 15 leght long integers

Answer (score 0):

```
$page_record = new Page();

$page_record->name = $page->name;
$page_record->access_token = $page->token;
$page_record->page_id = $page->id;
```

You're creating a new page, but prior to saving it you're attempting to set `page_id` property to `id` property, which will not exist until you call `save` on the page record.  You're getting the error because its trying to insert `null` for every single `page_id` column because of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the laravel validation. When you set rules, you can just tell wich column has to be unique. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation